# How to use TO_TIMESTAMP and TO_DATE in node-oracledb NodeJS

Tags: node.js, oracle, express, timestamp, node-oracledb

I have a requirement to insert data into my oracle DB using my Nodejs Application. I am using the node-oracledb framework to perform this operation. I can do CURD operation with this. When I try to insert time stamp and date field(using  to_date), it throws error "`ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected TIMESTAMP got NUMBER\n`"

Below is my input arguments which I will be using to insert in my Oracle database.

```
  req.body.CREATE_TS = new Date('02-09-2014 00:30:00').getTime();
  req.body.EFF_DTE = new Date('07-12-2014 00:30:00').getTime();
  req.body.SENT_TS = new Date('07-20-2014 00:30:00').getTime();
  req.body.LAST_UPDT_TS = new Date('10-20-2014 00:30:00').getTime();
  req.body.EFF_DTE = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ')
```

Is there any way to convert JavaScript date to Oracle date and JavaScript datetime to Oracle dattime. Something like `TO_DATE()` and `TO_TIMESTAMP()`.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you calling `getTime` on the date? Just leave the date a date.

It would help if you showed more of the code.

Given this table:

```
create table t (
  c date
)
/
```

Here's an example of inserting a date:

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const config = require('./dbConfig.js');

// date === 2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z (UTC)
let date = new Date(Date.UTC(2017, 00, 01, 00, 00, 00));

async function insertDate() {
  const conn = await oracledb.getConnection(config);

  await conn.execute(
    'insert into t (c) values (:d)',
    {
      d: date
    },
    {
      autoCommit: true
    }
  );
}

insertDate();
```

The most important part is that you get the timezone right. If you're using DATE or TIMESTAMP columns then you should be extra careful.

Be sure to review this doc:
https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#-9163-fetching-date-and-timestamps

The easiest solution is to set the ORA_SDTZ environment variable prior to running Node.js.

Also, check out these slides (9-17 are related to dates):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/69jt5uu1fqus84c/Tips%20and%20Tricks%20for%20Getting%20Started%20with%20the%20Oracle%20Database%20Driver%20for%20Node.pdf?dl=0